# Notepad++ isn't showing "Update Notepad++" menu item

Tags: notepad++

I can't find [the suggested](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Auto_Updates) *manual update* or *auto-update* feature in menu/settings of Notepad++.

I don't use a proxy. Just a direct Internet connection.

[image: notepad++]

Comment: +
http://i.stack.imgur.com/TAuVR.png

Comment: What version of Notepad++ do you have currently (from About menu item)?

Comment: It appears you have the minimalist package installed.  Explained by **No theme, no plugin, no updater, quick download and play directly. 7z format.**

Answer (score 18):

There are four [different versions](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.3.html) and you need the Installer version.

```
Installer: Take this one if you have no idea which one you should take.
zip package: Don't want to use installer? Check this one (zip format).
7z package: Don't want to use installer? 7z format.
minimalist package: No theme, no plugin, no updater
```

The update helper GPU.exe is only bundled with the Installer version.
Even the .zip and .7z version don't come with the auto update functionality.

The update helper is located under `...\notepad++\updater\GUP.exe`

Answer (score 4):

There could have been a problem during installation.  Try uninstalling and reinstalling Notepad++.

Comment: ok, I used ZIP package, where it is not included

Comment: And...? what happened, is it able to update?

Comment: no, it seems it is not included in portable version :(, so I installed regular one...